# Avoiding calls to mscorlib when comparing strings?

Tags: c#, mscorlib

Is there a possible way that let me compare strings without calling the op_Equality function is mscorlib?
For example:

```
string s1 = "hi";
if(s1 == "bye")
{
Console.Writeline("foo");
}
```

Compiles to:

```
IL_0003: call bool [mscorlib]System.String::op_Equality(string, string)
```

And looking at op_Equality at mscorlib from GAC it calls another method Equals(string, string)
Code:

```
public static bool Equals(string a, string b)
{
   return a == b || (a != null && b != null && string.EqualsHelper(a, b));
}
```

it uses the op code bne.une.s to compare those strings.

Now back at my question, how can I compare 2 strings without calling any function from the mscorlib like the method Equals does.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid mscorlib?

Comment: You could write your own method, perhaps by iterating over the characters. But what would be the point?

Comment: Chances are any method you write will not be as fast as the built-in one, either.  The built-in method uses unsafe code to do the equality check pretty efficiently.

Comment: Use Mono; this will avoid mscorlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now back at my question, how can I compare 2 strings without calling any function from the mscorlib like the method Equals does.

You can't - at least not without writing your own string comparison method from scratch.

At some point, you'd have to at least call `String.Equals(a,b)` (in order to have the private `EqualsHelper` method called, which does the actual comparison), which is also defined in `mscorlib`.

You could call `Equals` directly if you wish to avoid the operator call, though:

```
string s1 = "hi";
if (string.Equals(s1, "bye"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("foo");
}
```

This would avoid the call to `op_Equality`, bypassing it and calling `Equals` directly.

That being said, there is really no reason to avoid calling `op_Equality` on strings in the first place...

Comment: But how does the String.Equals method actually compare those 2 strings? I mean there must be a way.

Comment: @Furious Just edited with more details.  It's using a private method (`string.EqualsHelper`), which is also defined in `mscorlib` - since it's private, you can't call it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are asking for a string comparison function. Strings are basically arrays of characters that you can index in a similar fashion. Here is a simple string comparison algorithm.

```
public static bool Equals(string left, string right)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(left, null)) return ReferenceEquals(right, null);
    if (left.Length != right.Length) return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < left.Length; i++)
    {
        if (left[i] != right[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Having shown you that, there is no reason to avoid the mscorlib implementation, since my example makes several calls to mscorlib.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to compare:

```
        string s1 = "Hello";

        bool same = s1.CompareTo("Hello") == 0;
        bool different = s1.CompareTo("GoodBye") != 0;

        Console.WriteLine(same);
        Console.WriteLine(different);
```

In this case, both should report "True" to the console.

Another way:

```
    private static bool CheckEqual(string s1, string s2)
    {
        char[] c1 = (s1 == null) ? new char[0] : s1.ToCharArray();
        char[] c2 = (s2 == null) ? new char[0] : s2.ToCharArray();

        if (c1.Length != c2.Length) { return false; }

        for (int i = 0; i < c1.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!c1[i].Equals(c2[i])) { return false; }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `CompareTo` is provided by mscorlib

Comment: MSDN about `0` for `CompareTo`: *"This instance has the same position in the sort order as strB."* So, they're surely equivalent, but not guaranteed to equal. I'm not sure about actual behavior, to be honest, but I'd recommend you not to rely on anything that is not explicitly stated. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx

Comment: @Mudu plus, `CompareTo` could be less efficient than `Equals`.  If you have long strings, of different lengths, that begin with the same substring, Equals will return false immediately after checking the length, but CompareTo will have to iterate through the strings until it finds a mismatched character.

Comment: True, this does not address NOT using mscorlib, and is also not the best way to compare two strings. The best way would be the way your are trying to avoid, but using .Equals rather than the  == operator, as it will just fall to .Equals anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the `String` class is provided by `mscorlib`, there is absolutely no way to compare two strings without using `mscorlib`.  Even just using the indexer to get each character calls into `mscorlib`.

The only way to avoid `mscorlib` is to not use the .Net runtime, but that's pretty difficult if you want to use C#.

Comment: @phoog - Yeah, I suppose, but then the OP would be asking questions about how to avoid whatever assembly is the Mono equivalent of mscorlib.

Comment: That's no doubt true.  I just wanted to point out that there are ways to use C# without using the .NET runtime.